# How do I select the xref completion buffer using the keyboard?

Tags: completion, xref

Prior to the appearance of xref hitting M-v would switch to the completions buffer. Now this does not appear to work however.

I am running `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1265.21)` (aka Mac Emacs).

Comment: `M-v` is usually bound to `scroll-down-command` (and has behaved that way by default for as long as I can remember).

Comment: @phils `M-v` is bound to `switch-to-completions` in `minibuffer-local-completion-map` (see `simple.el`).

Comment: Does work for me with `GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8)`. Which emacs version are you running? Please add that info to the question. Have you already tried to reproduce the problem with `emacs -Q`? If not please do so.

Comment: Emacs 26.1, see above. Same behaviour when running `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @Tobias Does it work for you on Emacs 26.1? I doesn't work for me on Emacs 25.1 either which is suspicious.